# How many possible two-input logic gates are there?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In this post I am will make no difference between a logic gate and a formula in predicate logic.

I wonder how many possible logic gates are there with two inputs (say $A$ and $B$). The corresponding truth table has 4 rows for various values of $A$ and $B$ and each row has output one or zero - multiplying the number of logic gates by two. So, I would say there are $2^4 = 16$ possible two-input logic gates.

However, I am not sure how do formulas like $AND(A,B)$ which is symmetric with respect to $A$ and $B$, and formulas like $A$, which do not depend on all variables, affect the result.

Comment: If you think the answer may not be $2^4$, you are going to have explain in more detail what the problem is.  There are certainly $16$ functions $f:\{0,1\}^2 \to \{0,1\}$

Comment: Thanks for answering, I thought that some of the 16 functions might be the same function.

Comment: Your logic gate should output $1$ or $0$ (or T or F, or some similar pair), and for the same inputs should give consistent outputs every time.   If by "nothing" you mean $0$, then yes, a logic gate which outputs $0$ for all inputs is still a logic gate

Comment: It is easy enough to write out all 16 functions in a table - if you haven't already done so, then I encourage you to do it at least once - it'll help you understand how this works. If you compare any two of those 16 functions, you will always find that there is at least one input pair $(A, B)$ for which the two functions will have a different output - which means they are indeed distinct functions.